# Data use for email to multiple recipients

Tags: email, data

Does sending a large email message to multiple recipients use more data than sending the same email to only one recipient?

Answer (score 1):

No. The large email will be uploaded to the server only once, regardless of how many recipients it has. The server will then take care of sending this large email to all its recipients.

Answer (score 0):

The space used in your mailbox/server is independent from the number of receivers and also the data used to upload the file online.